# NoClassDefFoundError XmlSchema with IVY dependency

Tags: dependencies, wicket, apache-axis, ivy

In my Java Wicket application with Apache Ivy and JBoss I'm using a dynamic web project (Axis2). On the method

> populateAxisService() throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault

I get the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema

The ivy.xml contains the xmlschema dependency:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ws.xmlschema" name="xmlschema-core" rev="2.0.3">
    <artifact name="xmlschema-core" ext="jar" />
</dependency>
```

I don't understand why I am getting the NoClassDeffFoundError, as the correct dependency is set. Did someone encounter this before? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information supplied to provide any support. Are you certain the XML schema jar has been loaded correctly onto the classpath? This may have nothing to do with ivy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough context to be sure, but I guess that the xmlschema-core jar is not added to your classpath. Probably because the `packaging` of this module is `bundle` (see its pom.xml) where somewhere you specify that you want the artifact of type `jar`. Change your type filtering from `jar` to `jar,bundle` and things should work then smoothly.